# DeepStack - Prepare dataset / custom models with Python and LabelIMG

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5, lxml

I'm looking to buy Blue Iris as it incorporates DeepStack AI and the capability to train custom models.

I started to follow the DeepStack win / PC "Prepare dataset / custom models" guide, see below
https://docs.deepstack.cc/custom-models/datasetprep/index.html#step-1-install-labelimg

1. Install Python 3.10.7 (ok)
2. Type `pip3 install pyqt5 lxml` in Python - however this syntax does not work?

I hope someone can provide guidance to resolve this issue or recommend an alternative option.

Comment: "Does not work" is a very poor problem description. Did you add Python to your `PATH`? `pip3` should probably be `pip` if you are on Windows. Going forward, please search before asking, and please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi tripleee, thanks for your reply. Yes I added Python to PATH at the start of Python installation. Perhaps I need to add it manually? "Does not work" = SyntaxError: invalid  syntax.